# replace value in column with most recent value using date criteria

Tags: sql, datefield

I have a table with multiple ids (30+) and 5+ quarters which need to be used in the where clause. Sample table1:

```
ID   date            qtr        Value
______________________________________
1    2014-01-12      2014Q1     0.123
1    2014-02-14      2014Q1     0.126
1    2014-03-23      2014Q1     0.232
1    2014-04-10      2014Q2     0.222
1    2014-06-12      2014Q2     0.226
2    2014-01-13      2014Q1     0.120
2    2014-02-24      2014Q1     0.132
2    2014-03-21      2014Q1     0.241
2    2014-04-11      2014Q2     0.299
2    2014-06-14      2014Q2     0.312
```

I want to write a query that will replace the values for each ID, per quarter, to the most recent value in that quarter using the date field. This is the resulting table I want:

```
ID   date            qtr        Value
______________________________________
1    2014-01-12      2014Q1     0.232
1    2014-02-14      2014Q1     0.232
1    2014-03-23      2014Q1     0.232
1    2014-04-10      2014Q2     0.226
1    2014-06-12      2014Q2     0.226
2    2014-01-13      2014Q1     0.241
2    2014-02-24      2014Q1     0.241
2    2014-03-21      2014Q1     0.241
2    2014-04-11      2014Q2     0.312
2    2014-06-14      2014Q2     0.312
```

Here is the query I have so far.. but getting errors:

```
select id, qtr, month(date) as date1, date, value
from table1 
where qtr = '2014Q1' and id = '1'
group by id, qtr, date, month(date), value
Having month(convert (varchar, date, 112)) = max(month(date))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Start with a query that returns the max date per qtr per id.
2. Join that back to the table on qtr, id, and date to get the most "recent" row.
3. Join that back to the table again but this time on qtr and id and use the value from #2.

Or, depending on what DBMS you're using, you can use the FIRST_VALUE() function to do it without all the joins. But that's only if the database you're using it supports that function, such as DB2.